# Creating transaction family and run it locally gives invalid argument error sawtooth

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I tried to create a transaction family by referring this -> https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-javascript/tree/master/examples/intkey

As the first step I copy and paster the same codebase in handler.js and index.js (I didn't change anything in this code for now). Then I tried to run it locally and check whether it works. But when I run it using `node index.js` it asked me for another argument which is "validator address". Then I provided the `8008` address which is my sawtooth rest validator address. But it gives me the below error.

[image]

Then since it mentions zmq.connect, I provided 4004 since it is the TCP port. (I tried 4040 also since port 4004 is sometimes exported to port 4040 in Sawtooth). It also gives me the same error.

What should I provide as the validator address in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and see `node index.js tcp://127.0.0.1:4004`